# Centering text with word spacing and background image

Tags: css, center, word-spacing

I'm trying to get a text within div to be entered with word spacing and image in the background.
An example of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image: Text centered with image inside]

Her's a fiddle that shows what I achieved so far:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  background: url("http://s33.postimg.org/twxfn1by7/Playlist_Triangle.png") top center no-repeat;
  background-size:50px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>
Some text
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is problem here?

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/wes2sa1t/

You'd have to wrap the words in something like a span so you can center them. This is how to do it with CSS, as you tagged this with the CSS tag, but you could also achieve this with jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<h2>
<span>Some</span> <span>text</span>
</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  background: url("http://s33.postimg.org/twxfn1by7/Playlist_Triangle.png") top center no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than centering something, it more seems like you want the image evenly spaced between the words. I agree w/ Blaine that the words need to be wrapped in a span. I don't agree with setting a fixed width though, as that is very constraining.

Instead, I would move the background image from the h2 and place it on a psuedo-element of one of the spans:

```
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 0; // gets rid of whitespace between the spans
}

span {
  font-size: 24px; // resets the font-size of the words
}

span:nth-child(1):after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("http://s33.postimg.org/twxfn1by7/Playlist_Triangle.png") top center no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
}
```

Using inline-block places everything right next to each other, and putting a font-size: 0 on the h2 removes any whitespace.

Now the words can be any length, and the image will remain perfectly spaced between them.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rq8u5b3k/1/

If you can't control the markup for whatever reason, here's a jQuery snippet that will wrap each word in a span:

```
var words = $("h2").text().split(" ");
$("h2").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("h2").append($("<span>").text(v));
});
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rq8u5b3k/3/